# dot net 3.5 app to run on IIS7.5

Tags: .net-4.0, iis-7.5

Hi I have an application which has a main project set to ver 3.5 with some utility projects set to ver 2.0. I need to migrate the app to work on IIS7.5. I have tried recompiling the app as is and putting it on the server but to no avail.
What do I need to do to get this app running on 7.5? Will I need to upgrade the projects in the solution to .net 4.0?

any pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't necessary need to upgrade to .NET 4.0 even if it could be nice :-) All you need is to make sure the application pool is set to use CLR 2.0 in IIS and it will run just fine (obviously .NET 3.5 needs to be installed on the server).

Comment: Thanks, I can get it running ok but I'm having issues with the ioc container - which inturn is messing with nhibernate - An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory

Comment: Setting the application pool's identity to LocalSystem fixed it - thanks for your help. I am running on localhost btw.